# Calling RestAPI from java : No AuthenticationProvider found UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken

Tags: java, spring, rest, httpclient

I am just trying to call a rest api using the code below

```
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf;
CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider;
HttpClient httpClient;

final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Constructor.class);

public Constructor() {
    try{
    sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(SSLContext.getDefault(), NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);

    credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(
            ConfigData.getInstance().getSAEUsername(), ConfigData.getInstance().getSAEPassword()));
    httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
            .build();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

public String callAPI() {
    String jsonResponse = "";
    try {
        String s = "111.11.11.11";   
        //String s1 = "username"; // this works fine
        String s1 = "domain\username"; //AuthenticationProvider found Error
        String s2 =  "password";    
        String endpoint = "https://" + s + ":3600/Xxxxxxx/Yyyyyy/Ccccccc";
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(endpoint);
        request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        request.addHeader("accept", "application/json");//

        byte[] credentials = Base64.encodeBase64(
                (s1 + ":" + s2)
                        .getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        String s3 = new String(credentials, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        request.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + s3);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
        jsonResponse = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        LOGGER.info("Response: " + jsonResponse);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return jsonResponse;
}
```

Here if the username is just "username" (Eg: admin) the i get proper response but if the username is part of a domain like "domain\username"(Eg: DAAK\admin) then i get below error in response:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 401 </title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 401</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /Xxxxxxx/Yyyyyy/Ccccccc. Reason:
<pre>    No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken</pre></p>
<hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i>
</body>
</html>
```

I do not know Srings framework. Is there a simple fox for this?

Comment: it looks like the server you're communicating with expects username without domain, and does other things if it sees a domain that don't work.  Did you build the server?  Why do you expect `domain\username` to work?  I'd recommend working with however is point on the server to resolve this.

Comment: When i call this api from postman with domain\username then it works fine.

Comment: look at the outbound http for each, are there any differences?

Answer (score 0):

Basic authentification consist only of username:password, you can't use the domaine here.

Why do you need to provide the domain ?

Comment: without domain authenicaction fails

Comment: When i use postman with same domain\username then postman works with basic auth

Comment: Credentials defaultcreds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password");
httpClient.getState().setCredentials(new AuthScope("myhost", 80, AuthScope.ANY_REALM), defaultcreds);